# regular expression for left bracket three digits right bracket i.e. [123] or [368] and replace with ''

Tags: regex, perl, replace, sed

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match 5 character strings like the two strings shown in the title.  Here's a sample input string.

```
This is a sentence that doesn't contain any matches of the regex.  
This is a sentence that has two matches of the string at the end of the sentence [411] [101].  
This is a sentence that has three matches [876] [232] [323].
```

I would like to see a solution in perl or sed to remove these strings from a text file and also a solution to simply remove this string from short strings.  I'm new to regular expressions, perl, and sed. I tried using a reverse regular expression tool that seemed to give me this regular expression, but I couldn't find a way to put it to use with perl or sed.

```
\\[\\d\\d\\d\\]
```

I then tried something like this with perl and didn't get any farther.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\\[\\d\\d\\d\\]/""/g' textFileToRemoveRegexMatches.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
my $str = 'word [123] word [456]';
my $regex = qr/\[\d{3}\]/p;
my $subst = '';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;
```

But perhaps you want to use the command [**`sed`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). e.g.

```
sed 's/\[\d{3}\]//g' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Perl:

```
$ echo 'one[876] two[232] three[323]' | perl -pe 's/\[\d{3}\]//g;'
```

Prints:

```
one two three
```

Solution in Sed:

```
$ echo 'one[876] two[232] three[323]' | sed 's/\[[[:digit:]]\{3\}\]//g;'
```

Prints:

```
one two three
```

Those examples used the real-time command-line interface, but you can also put the code into script files for reuse, like so:

Perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -p
# purge-bracket-numbers.perl
s/\[\d{3}\]//g
```

Sed script:

```
#! /usr/bin/sed -f
# purge-bracket-numbers.sed
s/\[[[:digit:]]\{3\}\]//g
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
>>> s = "Hello world [123] this is some text"
>>> e = r'\[\d{3}\]'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(e, '', s)
'Hello world  this is some text'
```

If you want to do this on a large scale, consider using *sed* which is the **s**tream **ed**itor. It is available on all Linux flavors in addition to being a core utility on macOS.

I created a sample file with these two lines:

```
This is line one with [123] and needs to be substituted.
This is a longer line, lets call it line 2 that has [this thing] that should not be replaced, but [345] that should.
```

The way you use sed is to pass it a substitution expression. The command `s` means substitute, and `g` means substitute all occurrences, not just the first match.

Next, you put the expression want to search for, and the replacement in between to characters. The common norm is to use `/`, but you can use any two similar characters that don't have special meanings in your shell.

So, the sed command is:

```
sed s/search-for-this/replace-with-this/g the-name-of-the-file.txt
```

If you type the above, sed will simply return what it substitutes. Here is an example with our regular expression:

```
$ sed 's/\[[0-9]\{3\}\]//g' test.txt
This is line one with  and needs to be substituted.
This is a longer line, lets call it line 2 that has [this thing] that should not be replaced, but  that should.
```

The default behavior of sed is to return the results; and it does not modify the original file (as it is designed to work on *streams*).

To get sed to change the original file, pass the `-i` argument, which means *in-place* - that is, do the substitution in the file itself, like this:

```
$ sed -i 's/\[[0-9]\{3\}\]//g' test.txt
```

Note that this time, it did not return anything, however, if we check the file it has been modified:

```
$ cat test.txt
This is line one with  and needs to be substituted.
This is a longer line, lets call it line 2 that has [this thing] that should not be replaced, but  that should.
```

*Note: if you are on a mac, you may need to use `sed -i '.bak'`*